# FCM Notifications MySql Android (What to use as Unice "id")

Tags: android, mysql, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am doing a litle project where i want to send Push Notifications from my webpage (cron job).

Everything is good and works fine, but i dont like my idea anymore.

So what i have and why i have :

User instals the app, he will get Token for his device, it will be inserted to my MySQL database, and also i grab users IMEI for "Unice ID".

When this IMEI exists then i will just UPDATE the token in DB..

Everything is cool, and works fine, but i dont want to ask "Phone premission" it gets users confused why i want to access it, and sometimes they dont give access beacause of that.

So my Question is : what to use for unice ID (so that i can match it with user).
Also i dont want to ask for user e-mail etc, Ideal idea is so :

User opens APP only Internet premission is asked and he can get the latest events Notifications.

Also stupid question : 
Does the Android side Token "renew" in some time, or it will be updated and renewed only when App is installed / Reinstalled?

Comment: Why not just use the InstanceId you get for the push notifications as your ID?

Comment: Better question is that, should i even worry about token change?

and also i have two type of notifications..
Lets say : 
1. User
2. Power user

1. User gets just message when event will happen
2. Power user will get two notification, where one is more detailed.

Every user can be power user when they mark Checkbox on the app.

Comment: Yes you need to worry about changes to the InstanceId, if you dont send that change to your server the user wont get push notifications because you are sending to an invalid ID

Comment: I am pretty new when it gets to the FCM.. When i already have aquired the token, then i probaly need just ask it somehow inside the same class where i get the token?  Found that from doc : public String getId ()
Also: Google Play services
Returns a stable identifier that uniquely identifies the app instance.

Returns
The identifier for the application instance.

Comment: You should also have a `FirebaseInstanceIdService` where you get notified when the token needs to be refreshed because it became invalidated

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getId();

result : cyDvwMSjHMk
Thank you, my issue should now be solved :).